# elementwise conjugate but not conjugate homomorphisms

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

Does there exist a finite group $G$ and two group homomorphisms $\rho_1,\rho_2:G\to PGL(2,\mathbb{C})$ such that

(i) For all $g\in G$ there exists $M=M(g)\in PGL(2,\mathbb{C})$ such that $\rho_1(g)=M\rho_2(g)M^{-1}$.

(ii) There is no $M\in PGL(2,\mathbb{C})$ such that for all $g\in G$ we have $\rho_1(g)=M\rho_2(g)M^{-1}$.

The point of course is that I'm changing the order of the quantifiers around. One might say that $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ were elementwise conjugate, but not conjugate.

I am almost certain that if I replace $PGL(2,\mathbb{C})$ by $PGL(n,\mathbb{C})$ then such a group exists; indeed I might even have seen an explicit example once. But I am a bit unclear about whether I can get away with $n=2$.

Note that it's easy to check that (i) implies that the kernels of $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ are the same, and from this one can reduce to the case that both $\rho_i$ are injective. By the classification of finite subgroups of $PGL(2,\mathbb{C})$ one can hence assume that $G$ is either cyclic, dihedral, or isomorphic to $A_4$, $S_4$ or $A_5$; the cyclic case is easy to deal with, but the other cases seem to be asking me to get my hands quite dirty, and I'm wondering if I can avoid the mess by thinking about things in a different way.

Note that if we replace $PGL$ with $GL$ then such a group does not exist; [the analog of] (i) implies that $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ have the same traces everywhere, so by character theory they are isomorphic and [the analog of] (ii) fails. But with $PGL$ life is a little more difficult.